# Exceptions while doing socket programming in java

Tags: java, tcp

i am new at socket programming in java. while running the client code i face these exceptions. i don't understand how to overcome it ! 
here is my client code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class SOCK_1_CLIENT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SOCK_1_CLIENT client = new SOCK_1_CLIENT();
        client.run();


    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket("local host",5050);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("Hello to server from client");
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
        String msg = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

these are the exceptions..!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: local host
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at SOCK_1_CLIENT.run(SOCK_1_CLIENT.java:18)
    at SOCK_1_CLIENT.main(SOCK_1_CLIENT.java:11)
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `local host` with `localhost`.

Comment: now only out of that portion is displayed
if (msg != null)
  {
   PrintStream ps = new PrintStream (sock.getOutputStream());
   ps.println("message recieved");
  }